# Sorting dates in this format (DD-MM-YYYY)

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, datetime, comparative-review

Is this the correct and an elegant way to sort the dates in the format (DD-MM-YYYY) in ascending order?

```
let dates = ['01-02-2018', '02-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '31-12-2017'];

dates.sort((date1, date2) => {
    date1 = date1.split('-'), date2 = date2.split('-');
    let day1 = parseInt(date1[0]);
    let day2 = parseInt(date2[0]);
    let month1 = parseInt(date1[1]);
    let month2 = parseInt(date2[1]);
    let year1 = parseInt(date1[2]);
    let year2 = parseInt(date2[2]);
    if (year1 !== year2) {
        return year1 - year2;
    } else if (month1 !== month2) {
        return month1 - month2;
    } else {
        return day1 - day2;
    }
});
```

There is also this way, as Cris Luengo said in the comments, I can directly compare the strings.

```
let dates = ['01-02-2018', '02-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '31-12-2017'];

dates.sort((date1, date2) => {
    date1 = date1.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    date2 = date2.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    if (date1 < date2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (date1 > date2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Which way is more performant? How do I measure that?

Comment: You don't need to parse the strings at all. A sort on characters is sufficient. If the dates were stored in the proper order (ISO format, YYYY-MM-DD), then a direct string comparison would work. Here you can compare strings `date1[2]` to `date2[2]`, if those are equal, compare `[1]`, etc.

Comment: Right, but in my case, the days come first. So this comparison `'31-12-2017' < '02-01-2018';` will return false.

Comment: Do you suggest reordering the date to be in this format (YYYY-MM-DD) and then comparing the strings?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment, now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings within your application. At the earliest possible time, convert them to proper `Date` objects, and if a string representation is necessary, convert them to a `String` at the latest possible time. This way, you have the benefit of easy handling all throughout your applicaiton. This code would just be `dates.sort ( (a, b) => return a - b );`

Comment: Convert the date to a number `Number( YYYYMMDD)` sort on that number, then to string  `str = ""+num[i]` and extract day month year using `str.substr` using for loops to iterate, is 25% faster than any of the existing answers.

Comment: @Alexander I hate JavaScript date implementation and normally am staying away from them. It's much better IMO, to use ISO 8601 date representation for as long as possible (which is until you need to do date arithmetic) -- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss`. And when it comes to date arithmetic, use a library like moment.js or date-fns, anything but the damn native Date with horrible API.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko A third party date type is fine too, but not this mess of string processing.

Comment: @Alexander if the dates were in ISO 8601, no processing is needed in the first place

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Until you want to add a week to a date. Or get the duration of time between dates. String representations of things like URLs, dates and times are almost always a pain to work with. Just because they *can* be encoded as strings, doesn't mean they should. Just try treating file paths as strings, see how fun that becomes ("Should I add a trailing slash, or does it already have one?", "or crap, now I need to process a "../foo" relative link"). There's a reason why we create these abstractions over bytes, strings ,etc.

Comment: @Alexander assuming the requirements are not known in advance (which is always the case), you're right. Yet, do NOT recommend the native JS Date object. It has issues of exactly the same nature.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Yes, use a third party one. But just because the native JS date object api is poor doesn't mean we should degenerate to ISO 8601 strings all over the place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71202/discussion-between-igor-soloydenko-and-alexander).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You can run performance tests I prepared based on various code samples from the answers to this question: https://jsperf.com/cr-se-date-array-sorting/1. When I ran them, I see that my code is *second* best performing. The best is the one by @Kevin Cline (up voted!).

[image]

---

Here's my take on it. The following code uses the same idea about the string representation of date that is directly comparable for sorting.

It is not possible to tell in advance how performant will this solution be compared to one you presented above. It all depends **a lot** on how many dates are being sorted. If you deal with tons of dates, there will be many more invocations to the arrow function we're passing to `sort(...)`. Therefore, it's not good to keep translating the date via `split()` every time our arrow function is being used.

Instead, I recommend three steps:

1. Translate dates into a sortable representation (one time). Use `.map()`.
2. Do the sorting with `.sort()`.
   The values will be put in a lexicographical order.
3. Translate the sorted dates back into original representation.

This will guarantee that each date is translated **at most** twice, which makes the entire solution more performant for large `N`s.

Also, Notice that steps #1 and #3 can use same exact implementation, which I extracted.

---

```js
const reverseDateRepresentation = date => {
  let parts = date.split('-');
  return `${parts[2]}-${parts[1]}-${parts[0]}`;
};

const sortedDates = ['01-02-2018', '02-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '31-12-2017']
  .map(reverseDateRepresentation)
  .sort()
  .map(reverseDateRepresentation);

console.log(sortedDates);
```

Produces result:

> ```
> ["31-12-2017", "01-01-2018", "02-01-2018", "01-02-2018"]
> ```

---

Little note. I think, that from the "big O" point of view we haven't improve the algorithm. Since `.map(reverseDateRepresentation)` is \$O(n)\$, the performance of the entire solution is limited by the `.sort()` (which is [probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234683/javascript-array-sort-implementation) \$O(n * {\log n})\$). The way we're *potentially* improving solution is by making sure that the constants in our "big O" cost are as small as we can achieve.

Nevertheless, if we'd put the performance as top criteria of the solution, I'd learn as much as I can about the real data being processed; as well as conducted a thorough performance test.

In real life scenario, however, *I personally never put performance above readability*, because I believe that lack of readability is eventually the same thing as lack of correctness ...and correctness is *almost always* more important than performance (few exceptions are known though).

Comment: I don't think this could be any better, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what's happening here, How does `String.localeCompare` function know that it should compare the first argument with the second one, not the opposite? Is that the default behavior?

Comment: @MarkAdel yeah, that's how functions work in JavaScript. But scp713 made a good point. Even the `String.localeCompare` is not needed. We can just have `.sort()` without any arguments, since `String.localeCompare` is default

Comment: Awesome! You can edit your answer now to reflect his suggestion.

Comment: Read and fully understood the note, it makes sense. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Take a look at @Tushar's approach, it looks nice too.

Comment: @MarkAdel doing the transformation inside the `.sort()` is exactly what I was trying to avoid in my answer. Otherwise, the Date/timestamp idea may or may not improve the performance when compared to string-centric implementation.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: "never put performance above readability" seems like a bit of an extreme statement - performance is critical for some applications (to the point that it's necessary to minimise constant factors), and even when it isn't, picking algorithms with a much worse complexity will quickly lead to unacceptably slow performance.

Comment: @Dukeling you've took my words out of the context. Re-read the **entire paragraph** and see how we're in agreement there are cases performance is more important than correctness. I only know one case though, do you know more?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko In context: correctness might generally be more important than performance, but that doesn't say much about an *eventual* lack of correctness, and a *complete* lack of readability might lead to an eventual lack of correctness (assuming little testing and no rewrites), but that doesn't imply you should *always* pick even the smallest readability gains over massive performance gains (although maybe you're just talking about your personal experience, where performance has presumably never been particularly important, considering such an absolute "never" in your statement)

Comment: @dukeling well,  I am talking about my personal criteria I'm using when making choices about how to write code. Of course I may use "always" and "never" since I made it clear -- this is my reasoning, not a universally true or applicable one.

Answer (score 5):

Simply compare the characters in order from most significant to least significant:

```
let indices = [ 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 0, 1 ];
var dates = ["02-02-2018", "02-01-2018", "01-02-2018", "01-01-2018", "12-31-2017" ];

dates.sort((a, b) => {
    var r = 0;
    indices.find(i => r = a.charCodeAt(i) - b.charCodeAt(i));
    return r;
});
```

For each comparison this examines the minimum number of characters. Hard to imagine any other solution being faster, except maybe using a for loop instead of find.

Comment: Thank you, but I added the question under JavaScript tag, I expect the answers to be in JavaScript. I'm confused with this Java code, I'd appreciate it if you re-wrote it in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I have replaced the original code with tested Javascript.

Comment: It's simpler in Javascript :-)

Comment: It's clear now, That's a smart approach I like it! Check Igor's answer too it's very efficient.

Comment: In my opinion, readability suffers for a couple of reasons, but gosh this is the best performing solution so far!

Comment: I implemented it using a for loop and ran a performance test, It's ~4 times faster! Check https://jsperf.com/date-array-sorting/1

Comment: @MarkAdel: I wouldn't have expected the for loop to be 4x faster than the find. With a for loop instead of find this runs about 8 times faster than any other solution.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your update answer, I would like to offer a couple points. You could minimize the amount of 'custom' logic by using some bult-in functions. For example, your comparisons to determine which integer to return is functionally the same as [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Instead of `if`/`else`s you could write `return date1.localeCompare(date2);`.

Also, at the start of your comparison function, in plain English you are essentially joining the array, but in reverse order. Therefore, why not utilize `join` and `reverse`? In fact, you could knock out the whole string preparation in a one-liner: `date1.split('-').reverse().join('')`.

So the updated function would look like:

```
dates.sort((date1, date2) => {
    date1 = date1.split('-').reverse().join('');
    date2 = date2.split('-').reverse().join('');
    return date1.localeCompare(date2);
});
```

Comment: Doing `date.split('-').reverse().join('')` on each invocation to the sort arrow function is too costly. See my answer with an alternative.

Comment: @Igor Soloydenko I can't comment on your answer (too low rep) but now that I think about it, you could omit `String.localeCompare` and just use `.sort()` due to sort's default behavior.

Comment: Sure thing. One last thing is that [the Array.prototype.sort() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) say that "If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element", it doesn't mention localeCompare specifically

Answer (score 2):

As the code is reviewed in other answers, I'll suggest you to different approach.

```
let getTimestamp = str => +new Date(...str.split('-').reverse());
dates.sort((a, b) => getTimestamp(a) - getTimestamp(b));
```

The function `getTimestamp` will give the timestamp from the given string. This timestamp can be used in the `sort` function for comparing with other dates.

```js
let dates = ['01-02-2018', '02-01-2018', '01-01-2018', '31-12-2017'];

console.time('tushar');
let getTimestamp = str => +new Date(...str.split('-').reverse());
let sortedDates = dates.sort((a, b) => getTimestamp(a) - getTimestamp(b));

console.log(sortedDates);
console.timeEnd('tushar');
```

References:

1. [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
2. [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
3. [`...` Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

---

> Which way is more performant? How do I measure that?

To measure the performace, you may use [jsperf.com](https://jsperf.com/). Or simply, use [`console.time`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) as shown in the demo.

Comment: That's nice! But why not use `new Date().getTime()` instead of `+new Date()` which looks hacky.

Comment: @MarkAdel Yes. You can use `getTime()` as well, it is readable. `+` is short.

Comment: Unfortunately, string->Date parsing is costly, and it will limit the performance of the end result.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko Yes. I saw the comparison in your answer.